# set proofs A ∩ (B ∩ C ) = (A ∩ B) ∩ C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A,B,C be sets. Prove that : 
A ∩ (B ∩ C ) = (A ∩ B) ∩ C

I wasn't sure what proofs to use to approach this equation.

Comment: Take any Venn diagram?

Comment: The answer would depend on the context, which you have not given. Depending on that the answer could be anything from quite complicated to just "obviously". For example if you're allowed to use truth tables you could use that, if you're allowed to use associative law in logic you could use that, if you're allowed to use associative law for sets the statement is obvious. Btw have you done a serious try of proving it? Have you tried using the definition of intersection and set equality and see where that leads you? I actually don't see how you can go wrong or get stuck here...

Answer (score 2):

To show that $S = T$, you need to show two things: that $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$.

So for this problem, start with "let $x \in A \cap (B \cap C)$". Then, you know that $x \in A$ and $x \in B \cap C$. From there, how can you conclude that $x \in (A \cap B) \cap C$?

Then do the reverse direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the proposition that $x \in A$. Similarly define the propositions $b$ and $c$ for the sets $B$ and $C$. Notice that showing,

$$x \in A \cap (B \cap C) \iff x \in (A \cap B) \cap C$$

is the same as showing:

$$ a \wedge (b \wedge c) \iff a \wedge (b \wedge c).$$

which is a well known result in propositional logic.

In other words, a lot of the properties of sets arise naturally from the properties of propositional logic.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show two sets are equal is to show each is a subset of the other.
A more direct way to show they are equal, though, is to fix any element $x$ and show it's in one *iff* it's in the other. In this case, we have
\begin{align*}
x \in A \cap (B \cap C)
&\iff x \in A \land x \in B \cap C \\
&\iff x \in A \land (x \in B \land x \in C) \\
&\iff (x \in A \land x \in B) \land x \in C \\
&\iff (x \in A \cap B) \land x \in C \\
&\iff x \in (A \cap B) \cap C.
\end{align*}

This is what benguin is talking about in their answer: $\cap$ reduces logically to $\land$, and $\land$ is associative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E $ be the set of all such  $x $ that $x $ is in all three of sets $A$, $B $ and $C $.

If $x\in E$ then $x\in A $ and in both $B $ and $C $. so $x\in B\cap C $ and $x\in A $.  So $x \in A\cap (B\cap C)$.  And $x$ is in both $A $ and $B $ as well as in $C $ so $x \in (A\cap B)\cap C $.

So $E $ is a subset of both $A\cap(B\cap C) $ and of $(A\cap B)\cap C$.

If $y \in (A\cap B)\cap C $ the $y$ is in both $C $ and $A\cap B $, so $y $ is in $A $ and $B $.  So $y$ is in $A $, $B $ and $C $ so $y \in E $.

Likewise if $z \in  A \cap (B \cap C $ then $z \in A $ and in $B\cap C $ and so in $B $ and $C $ so $z \in E $.

So both $A\cap (B\cap C ) $ and $(A\cap B)\cap C $ are subsets of $E $ and have $E $ as a subset.  So both are equal to $E $ and therefore to each other.